# Não consigo pegar todos os dados do arquivo XML e salvar em um txt

Tags: java, xml

Esse é o XML:

```xml
<cv>
    <pessoa id="1">
        <dadosPessoais>
            <nome></nome>
            <sexo></sexo>
            <idade></idade>
        </dadosPessoais>
        <formação>
            <instituição nome="" país="">
                <curso anoIni="" anoFim="" nível="">
                </curso>
            </instituição>
        </formação>
        <formação>
            <instituição nome="" país="">
                <curso anoIni="" anoFim="" nível="">
                </curso>
            </instituição>
        </formação>
    </pessoa>
</cv>
```

Minha dificuldade é em ler os elementos que estão na *tag* Formação. Como existe mais de uma *tag* com o mesmo nome (formação), quando eu coloco para salvar em um `txt`, só mostra até os dados da primeira *tag* formação e no meu projeto a pessoa pode adicionar quantas formações quiser.

```java
try {
    doc = builder.build(f);
    root = (Element) doc.getRootElement();

    List<Element> pessoas = root.getChildren();

    for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++){                                     
        Element pessoaS = pessoas.get(i);

        try { // criar
            File diretorio = new File("c:\\CV");
            diretorio.mkdir(); //cria, se possível

            File arquivo = new File(diretorio, "cv_"+ pessoaS.getAttributeValue("id") +".txt");
            FileWriter fw;
            fw = new FileWriter(arquivo);
            BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            b.write("Nome: " + pessoaS.getChild("dadosPessoais").getChildText("nome"));
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Sexo: " + pessoaS.getChild("dadosPessoais").getChildText("sexo"));
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Idade: " + pessoaS.getChild("dadosPessoais").getChildText("idade"));
            b.write("\r\n\r\n");
            b.write(pessoaS.getChild("formação").getChild("instituição").getChild("curso").getAttributeValue("nível") + ": " + pessoaS.getChild("formação").getChild("instituição").getAttributeValue("nomeDaInstituicao")+ " (" + pessoaS.getChild("formação").getChild("instituição").getAttributeValue("nomePaisCurso") + ")");
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Curso: " + pessoaS.getChild("formação").getChild("instituição").getChildText("curso"));
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Início: " + pessoaS.getChild("formação").getChild("instituição").getChild("curso").getAttributeValue("anoIni"));
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Término: " + pessoaS.getChild("formação").getChild("instituição").getChild("curso").getAttributeValue("anoFim"));

            b.write("\r\n\r\n");

            b.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (JDOMException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa precisa recuperar uma lista de `Element` a partir do elemento `pessoa`, então depois percorrer esta lista. Da forma que você faz, recuperando um único `Element` `formação` irá recuperar apenas o primeiro nó `formação` encontrado no XML. A forma de recupera a lista de formações é simples, parecida com a forma com você está recuperando as pessoas:

```java
final List<Element> formacoes = pessoa.getChildren("formação");
```

Depois disto, basta percorrer cada formação, algo assim:

```java
for (int j = 0; j < formacoes.size(); j++) {
    final Element formacao = formacoes.get(j);

    // faz o que precisa ser feito
}
```

Este é um exemplo completo fazendo o que você precisa, acredito eu, usando JDom versão `2.0.2`:

```java
final SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
final File xml = new File("F:/CV/CV.xml");

final Document doc = builder.build(xml);
final Element root = doc.getRootElement();

final List<Element> pessoas = root.getChildren();

for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++) {
    final Element pessoa = pessoas.get(i);

    final File diretorio = new File("F:/CV");

    final File arquivo = new File(diretorio, "cv_" + pessoa.getAttributeValue("id") + ".txt");

    try (final FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo); final BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {

        final Element dadosPessoais = pessoa.getChild("dadosPessoais");

        b.write("Nome: " + dadosPessoais.getChildText("nome"));
        b.write("\r\n");
        b.write("Sexo: " + dadosPessoais.getChildText("sexo"));
        b.write("\r\n");
        b.write("Idade: " + dadosPessoais.getChildText("idade"));
        b.write("\r\n\r\n");

        final List<Element> formacoes = pessoa.getChildren("formação");
        for (int j = 0; j < formacoes.size(); j++) {
            final Element formacao = formacoes.get(j);
            final Element instituicao = formacao.getChild("instituição");
            final Element curso = instituicao.getChild("curso");
            b.write(curso.getAttributeValue("nível") + ": ");
            b.write(instituicao.getAttributeValue("nome"));
            b.write(" (" + instituicao.getAttributeValue("país") + ")");
            b.write("\r\n");

            b.write("Curso: " + curso.getText());
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Início: " + curso.getAttributeValue("anoIni"));
            b.write("\r\n");
            b.write("Término: " + curso.getAttributeValue("anoFim"));
            b.write("\r\n\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Como viu, percorremos tanto a lista de pessoas quanto a lista de formações da pessoa. O arquivo TXT gerado, usando este XML:

```xml
<cv>
    <pessoa id="1">
        <dadosPessoais>
            <nome>Bruno César</nome>
            <sexo>M</sexo>
            <idade>26</idade>
        </dadosPessoais>
        <formação>
            <instituição nome="UFG" país="Brazil">
                <curso anoIni="2009" anoFim="2014" nível="Graduação">Engenharia de Software</curso>
            </instituição>
        </formação>
        <formação>
            <instituição nome="UFSC" país="Brazil">
                <curso anoIni="2015" anoFim="2017" nível="Mestrado">Pós-Graduação em Ciência da Computação</curso>
            </instituição>
        </formação>
    </pessoa>
</cv>
```

Possui este conteúdo:

```
Nome: Bruno César
Sexo: M
Idade: 26

Graduação: UFG (Brazil)
Curso: Engenharia de Software
Início: 2009
Término: 2014

Mestrado: UFSC (Brazil)
Curso: Pós-Graduação em Ciência da Computação
Início: 2015
Término: 2017
```

Como dica, se possível for, evite usar caracteres especiais em nomes de *tags* e atributos do seu XML, isto poderá lhe gerar problemas no futuro.

Comment: Muito obrigada!! Funcionou perfeitamente :D